# NextJS always hard refreshing when behind Cloud Front CDN

Tags: next.js, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, next-router

I have a NextJS application that used `router.push(newRoute)` to change page.

Locally, pages change without any refresh, that is what I expect (on next documentation this is called "soft navigation").

Using AWS Amplify, I have deployed this application on a certain domain, let's call it `myDomain.com`: the application works correctly here also, pages change without any refresh (even here, we seem to have "soft navigation" happening).

I needed to add this application to a certain `myMasterDomain.com/next`.
In order to achieve this we used a Cloud Front CDN.

Here's the trouble: from `myMasterDomain.com/next`, every time I `router.push(newRoute)`, the page refreshes making the application impossible to use (here we seem to have "hard navigation" instead).

I have no idea where to look into. Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing this issue too.. Did you figure out a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your CloudFront forwards `Rsc` header to NextJS server.

I am also facing this issue. I found that during router.push(newRoute), the browser will make a request to newRoute with header `Rsc: 1`. NextJS server will respond differently if this header is missing.